# Reducing app updates size on google play store

Tags: android, google-play, apk, app-update, apksigner

Now most of the apps update size is much smaller than app download size but unfortunately I am not able to get this feature in my app however I have added following code in my app's build.gradle file but still I am not able to get the desired results.

```
buildTypes {
     release {
         minifyEnabled true
         shrinkResources true
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         signingConfig signingConfigs.config
         zipAlignEnabled true
     }
     debug {
         signingConfig signingConfigs.config
         zipAlignEnabled true
     } }
```

How can I achieve the desired results or what I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: You should try Instant Apps. https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play delivers patches to apps (the technology which makes the update smaller) based on demand. So if you are the only one updating your app, then a patch probably won't be generated. Or it might take a few days to get generated, until it is noticed that enough users need a patch. The patch being generated can also depend on multiple things, like which version of the Play store the user has, which version of Android, and which version of the app the user is upgrading from.

To estimate what the patch size will be when Play generates it for your app you can use [this open source library](https://github.com/googlesamples/apk-patch-size-estimator). It was [announced by Google Play in this blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/saving-data-reducing-the-size-of-app-updates-by-65-percent.html).

Comment: Thanks for the information but is there any official documentation so that I can achieve the required target.

Comment: The open source library comes from the people who write the Google Play serving stack, and is the official reference. See this blog post: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/saving-data-reducing-the-size-of-app-updates-by-65-percent.html